# Ancestry - Customize output from arrange_serializable method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I am using ancestry gem for categories model and when I call the method arrange_serializable I would like to have cusmized output and add there output from methods in the associated models.

Instead of: 
{ id: 1, name: "XYZ", children: { id: 11, name: "XYZ", children...} }

I need: 
{ id: 1, custom_method: "ABC", children: { id: 11, custom_method: "ABC", name: "XYZ", children...}}

I spent several days to figure out, but without any luck.

Any tip how to achieve this?

Thank you, Miro

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a custom arrange_serializable method. You can do something like this

```ruby
TreeNode.arrange_serializable do |parent, children|
  { id: parent.id, 
    custom_method: "ABC",
    children: children }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom_arrange method. This would work for your example.

```
def custom_arrange nodes = nil
    nodes = Post.arrange if nodes.nil?
    nodes.map do |parent, children|
       {
          id: parent.id,
          custom_method: "ABC",
          children: custom_arrange(children)
        }
    end
end
```